# What exactly happened between Walt and Gretchen?

Tags: breaking-bad

As we saw in *Breaking-Bad* there was something happening between Walt and Gretchen. Were they in love?  If yes, then why did they get separated from each other?

Comment: Although the *question* is not a duplicate, you can find the *answer* [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11014/why-exactly-did-walt-leave-grey-matter/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In one of the interviews if I recall Jessica Hecht (Gretchen) mentioned that Walt and Gretchen have been in love and dated. Once it got deeper, Walt got invited for a dinner to Gretchen's wealthy parents' home. Walt started having some kind of inferiority complex afterwards and they eventually broke up.

This is the [interview](http://www.amc.com/shows/breaking-bad/talk/2009/05/jessica-hecht-interview):

> **Q: What’s it like have Bryan Cranston curse at you?**
>
> A: Oh man, he’s a good actor. But it was easy because Vince Gilligan told us exactly what went down between the characters off screen: We were very much in love and we were to get married. And he came home and met my family, and I come from this really successful, wealthy family, and that knocks him on his side. He couldn’t deal with this inferiority he felt — this lack of connection to privilege. It made him terrified, and he literally just left me, and I was devastated. Walt is fighting his way out of going back to that emotional place, so he says, “F— you.”

Comment: See also: http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/50437/13595 .